# RPM-based Linux: How can I remove a locally installed package?

Tags: fedora, rpm

I tested installing a package for which I had to use `yum localinstall <pkgfile>.rpm`. Worked fine, but I cannot figure out how to remove it. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either `yum erase <package_name>` or `rpm -e <package_name>` should remove any installed package.  `yum localinstall` has been deprecated for some time, and in current versions of Fedora, as well as RHEL 8, it's simply an alias for `yum install`

Comment: ... or even `dnf install`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work after you install a local file RPM via `yum install *.rpm`.

Uninstalling via `yum erase *.rpm` throws this error: 
```
No Match for argument: <filename>.rpm
No Packages marked for removal
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, you shouldn't use the ".rpm" extension when erasing the package - just use the package name.

Answer (score 1):

I have just been through this process. The filename for the rpm package I installed was not the same as the package name.

It is possible to find packages that have been installed using `yum localinstall` by using `yum list | grep commandline`.

The package name will be on the left of the output of that command (there may of course be multiple packages if you've installed multiple rpms from files so you may have to find the one you want), and you can feed that to `yum erase` as indicated in patbarron's answer (i.e. `yum erase <package_name>`).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).